Discord.js Auto Register Slash Commands
Trying to build an index.js file that auto loads, auto reloads, and disables modules with errors in them to prevent the bot from crashing. This portion is working fine.
One of the modules that is loading is registerCommands.js where I am trying to auto register all slash commands that can be found in the various auto loaded modules.
I've been trying to figure this out for days so if someone could give me a bit of an understanding as to what I've done wrong here.
Index.js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const chokidar = require('chokidar');
const {
    Client,
    GatewayIntentBits,
    ActivityType,
    EmbedBuilder,
    ActionRowBuilder,
    ButtonBuilder,
    SlashCommandBuilder,
    PermissionFlagsBits,
    ModalBuilder,
    TextInputBuilder,
    TextInputStyle,
    PermissionsBitField,
    ChannelType,
    Events,
    Partials,
    StringSelectMenuOptionBuilder
} = require('discord.js');

let config = require('./config.js');
let guildConfig = require('./guildConfig.js'); // New addition

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildBans,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildEmojisAndStickers,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildIntegrations,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildWebhooks,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildInvites,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageTyping,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageReactions,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageTyping,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildScheduledEvents
    ],
    partials: [Partials.Channel]
});

const ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID = '0000'; // Replace with your specific channel ID in the admin guild

let logChannel = null;
const modules = new Map();

const getTimeStamp = () => {
    const now = new Date();
    const hours = String(now.getHours()).padStart(2, '0');
    const minutes = String(now.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0');
    const seconds = String(now.getSeconds()).padStart(2, '0');
    return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
};

const logMessage = async (message) => {
    const timestampedMessage = `[${getTimeStamp()}] ${message}`;
    originalConsoleLog(timestampedMessage); // Log to console
    if (logChannel) {
        try {
            await logChannel.send(`\`\`\`js\n${timestampedMessage}\n\`\`\``);
        } catch (error) {
            originalConsoleLog(`[${getTimeStamp()}] Error sending log message to Discord:`, error);
        }
    } else {
        originalConsoleLog(`[${getTimeStamp()}] Log channel not found. Unable to send log: ${message}`);
    }
};

// Override console.log to use logMessage function
const originalConsoleLog = console.log;
console.log = async (...args) => {
    const message = args.join(' ');
    await logMessage(message);
};

const initializeLogChannel = async () => {
    try {
        const guild = await client.guilds.fetch(config.adminGuild);
        logChannel = await guild.channels.fetch(ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID);
        if (!logChannel) {
            await logMessage(`Channel with ID ${ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID} not found in guild ${config.adminGuild}`);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        await logMessage(`Error fetching guild or channel: ${error.message}`);
    }
};

const loadModule = async (filePath) => {
    try {
        // Attempt to unload the module if it exists
        await unloadModule(filePath);

        delete require.cache[require.resolve(filePath)];
        const module = require(filePath);

        if (typeof module === 'function') {
            module(client, { config, guildConfig }); // Pass config and guildConfig to the module
            await logMessage(`Loaded module: ${filePath}`);
            modules.set(filePath, module);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        await logMessage(`Error loading module ${filePath}: ${error.message}`);
        await logMessage(`Unloaded module due to error: ${error.message}`);
    }
};

const unloadModule = async (filePath, error = null) => {
    if (modules.has(filePath)) {
        try {
            const module = modules.get(filePath);
            if (module.unload) {
                module.unload(client);
            }
            delete require.cache[require.resolve(filePath)];
            modules.delete(filePath);
            let message = `Unloaded module: ${filePath}`;
            if (error) {
                message += ` due to error: ${error.message}`;
            }
            await logMessage(message);
        } catch (unloadError) {
            await logMessage(`Error unloading module ${filePath}: ${unloadError.message}`);
        }
    }
};

const loadModules = async (dir) => {
    try {
        const files = fs.readdirSync(dir);

        for (const file of files) {
            const filePath = path.join(dir, file);

            if (fs.statSync(filePath).isDirectory()) {
                await loadModules(filePath);
            } else if (file.endsWith('.js')) {
                await loadModule(filePath);
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        await logMessage(`Error loading modules from directory ${dir}: ${error.message}`);
    }
};

client.once('ready', async () => {
    await logMessage(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    client.user.setActivity('Being built!', { type: ActivityType.Watching });

    await initializeLogChannel();

    // Load all modules from the ./bot-modules/ directory
    await loadModules(path.join(__dirname, 'bot-modules'));

    // Load and execute the register commands module
    require('./bot-modules/registerCommands')(client);

    // Start the watcher after loading all modules
    const watcher = chokidar.watch(path.join(__dirname, 'bot-modules'), {
        ignoreInitial: true
    });

    watcher.on('all', (event, filePath) => {
        if (filePath.endsWith('.js')) {
            if (event === 'change' || event === 'add') {
                console.log(`Reloading module: ${filePath}`);
                loadModule(filePath);
            } else if (event === 'unlink') {
                console.log(`Removing module: ${filePath}`);
                unloadModule(filePath);
            }
        }
    });

    // Watch the config.js and guildConfig.js files for changes
    const configWatcher = chokidar.watch([path.join(__dirname, 'config.js'), path.join(__dirname, 'guildConfig.js')], {
        ignoreInitial: true
    });

    const reloadConfigs = async (filePath) => {
        const configName = path.basename(filePath);
        console.log(`Reloading ${configName}`);
        delete require.cache[require.resolve(filePath)];

        if (configName === 'config.js') {
            config = require('./config.js');
            await logMessage(`Configuration reloaded: ${configName}`);
        } else if (configName === 'guildConfig.js') {
            guildConfig = require('./guildConfig.js');
            await logMessage(`Configuration reloaded: ${configName}`);
        }
    };

    configWatcher.on('change', reloadConfigs);
});

client.login(config.token);

registerCommands.js
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = async (client) => {
    const commands = [];
    client.commands = new Map();

    try {
        // Load command files
        const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname)).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js') && file !== 'registerCommands.js');
        for (const file of commandFiles) {
            console.log(`Loading command file: ${file}`);
            const command = require(path.join(__dirname, file));
            if (command.data && command.execute) {
                commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
                client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
                console.log(`Loaded command: ${command.data.name}`);
            } else {
                console.warn(`Skipping file: ${file} (missing data or execute)`);
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error loading commands:', error);
    }

    const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(client.token);

    client.once('ready', async () => {
        try {
            console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

            // Register commands for the guilds specified in the config
            const { adminGuild, memberGuild } = require('./config.js');
            const guildIds = [adminGuild, memberGuild];

            for (const guildId of guildIds) {
                // Register commands in the guild
                await rest.put(
                    Routes.applicationGuildCommands(client.user.id, guildId),
                    { body: commands }
                );
                console.log(`Successfully reloaded application (/) commands for guild ${guildId}.`);

                // Log the registered commands
                console.log('Registered commands:');
                commands.forEach(cmd => console.log(`- ${cmd.name}`));
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error registering application (/) commands:', error);
        }

        console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    });

    client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
        if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

        const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
        if (!command) return;

        try {
            await command.execute(interaction);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
        }
    });
};

A sample module with a slash command
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

console.log('Loading ping command...');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ping')
        .setDescription('Replies with Pong!'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        console.log('Executing ping command...');
        await interaction.reply('Pong!');
    },
};

config.js
const guildConfig = require('./guildConfig.js');

module.exports = {
    token: '000000',
    openAIApiKey: '000000',
    adminGuild: guildConfig.adminGuild.id,
    memberGuild: guildConfig.memberGuild.id,
    guildConfig
};

The guild ids are successfully being pulled so I'm not including the guildConfig.js file as that part is at least working.

and what is your issue now?

you're not listing any errors or following up on comments....maybe you've figured out your question and didn't come back here to close it?
